# How to apply cummax() till a particular value in a series in a column in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R , df. it looks like

```
> seq <- c(200,208, 212, 215, 218, 25,28, 232, 236, 245 , 247, 248, 249,265, 276, 284,298, 2, 12, 13, 17,
          152, 154, 159, 
          66, 69, 74, 81, 88, 91, 93, 94, 95, 96)
> cashreg <- rep(c('c1', 'c2', 'c3'), c(21, 3, 10))
> df <- data.table(seq, cashreg)
> df
    seq cashreg
 1: 200      c1
 2: 208      c1
 3: 212      c1
 4: 215      c1
 5: 218      c1
 6:  25      c1
 7:  28      c1
 8: 232      c1
 9: 236      c1
10: 245      c1
11: 247      c1
12: 248      c1
13: 249      c1
14: 265      c1
15: 276      c1
16: 284      c1
17: 298      c1
18:   2      c1
19:  12      c1
20:  13      c1
21:  17      c1
22: 152      c2
23: 154      c2
24: 159      c2
25:  66      c3
26:  69      c3
27:  74      c3
28:  81      c3
29:  88      c3
30:  91      c3
31:  93      c3
32:  94      c3
33:  95      c3
34:  96      c3
```

I have a maximum for the series defined by the user:

```
actual_maximum <- 299
```

I want to get a monotonous sequence before and after the `min(maximum_in_series , actual_maximum)` . here maximum_in_series is the maximum value for each "cashreg".

In order to find the maximum of the seq by "cashreg" I am trying to use

```
> df[df[,.I[which.max(seq)], by = cashreg]$V1]
   seq cashreg
1: 298      c1
2: 159      c2
3:  96      c3
```

I want to remove the out of sequence numbers before and after these maximum values. I am trying to use `cummax(seq)` for this for each `cashreg`.

`For Example:` in cashreg c1, I want to apply cummax(seq) till the min(max_series, actual_maximum), which is 298, and I want to remove the out of sequence numbers 25 and 28. then again it should calculate the maximum of seq of remaining series(2, 12, 13, 17) , in this case maximum will come as 17. so I want to apply cummax(seq) for this part.

This process should be done for each group of cashreg.

The expected output looks like.

```
    seq cashreg
 1: 200      c1
 2: 208      c1
 3: 212      c1
 4: 215      c1
 5: 218      c1
 6: 232      c1
 7: 236      c1
 8: 245      c1
 9: 247      c1
10: 248      c1
11: 249      c1
12: 265      c1
13: 276      c1
14: 284      c1
15: 298      c1
16:   2      c1
17:  12      c1
18:  13      c1
19:  17      c1
20: 152      c2
21: 154      c2
22: 159      c2
23:  66      c3
24:  69      c3
25:  74      c3
26:  81      c3
27:  88      c3
28:  91      c3
29:  93      c3
30:  94      c3
31:  95      c3
32:  96      c3
```

How can I do this with data.table in R.

Comment: Please show the expected otuput

Comment: @akrun I am adding the expected output in the question

Comment: @akrun I have posted the expected output

Answer (score 0):

```
for( i in unique(df$cashreg)){
  #i <- "c1"
  cr <- i
  df_cashreg <- df[cashreg == cr,]
  df1 <- df_cashreg[1:df_cashreg[,.I[which.max(seq)]]]
  df2 <- df_cashreg[(df_cashreg[,.I[which.max(seq)]]+1) : nrow(df_cashreg)]
  df1 <- df1[, .SD[seq == cummax(seq)],cashreg]
  df2 <- df2[, .SD[seq == cummax(seq)],cashreg]
  df_combined <- rbind(df1, df2)
  if(file.exists(file.path(path2data,"temp_cashreg_clean.txt"))){
    write.table(df_combined, file.path(path2data, "temp_cashreg_clean.txt"), 
                row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE,append = TRUE, sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
  }else{
    write.table(df_combined, file.path(path2data, "temp_cashreg_clean.txt"), 
                row.names=FALSE, col.names=TRUE,sep="\t", quote = FALSE)
  }
}

df <- fread(file.path(path2data, "temp_cashreg_clean.txt"), colClasses = 
            c(cashreg = "character"))
df <- unique(df)
file.remove(file.path(path2data, "temp_cashreg_clean.txt"))
```